# Return login error message in spring boot

Tags: spring, rest

I am implementing a rest api in spring boot and I want to return user data in the response as well as the jwt token if the login request is successful. If not, I want to return a message indicating that the password was incorrect or that the user does not exits.

This is my login method:

```
    public LoginResponseDTO loginUser(String username, String password){

        try {
            Authentication auth = authManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password)
            );

            String token = tokenService.generateJwt(auth);

            return new LoginResponseDTO(userRepository.findByUsername(username).get(), token);

        } catch (AuthenticationException e){
            return new LoginResponseDTO(e.toString());
        }
```

And this is the authentication manager:

```
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authManager(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthProvider.setHideUserNotFoundExceptions(false);
        daoAuthProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        daoAuthProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return new ProviderManager(daoAuthProvider);
    }
```

The case where the login is successful works, but when I enter a wrong password I get 'Bad credentials'. How can I make it return the UserNotFoundException message?